# cannot create directory : Read-only file system

Tags: filesystem, linux-headers

In my Linux system suddenly this msg start appearing "cannot create directory: Read-only file system"
Now I am not able to create any directory or not able to download anything. What should I do so that I can create a new directory.

Comment: File systems can turn read-only when there is a fault detected. This is to protect it from damage or corruption. Sometimes it's anomalous and you can just reboot. So reboot. If it keeps happening, then it's likely that the hard drive is failing and will soon need to be replaced.

Comment: Please explain, where you want to create the directory.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Which supported release? Read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Ok, I 'll try to reboot it.                                                                                                                 I tried everywhere to create a new directory : in Downlod folder, Documents, Desktop, but not able to create anywhere.                                                                                                                             yes, I am using Ubunt (Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS)

Comment: I would explore the logs looking at when/why it flipped from RW to RO, as whilst it maybe a once-off *dirty* power issue that won't occur; it maybe a warning clue of hardware problems on the way (*if you're unaware of a cause*).  You don't need to do anything the first time (I'd `fsck` from *live* media if it was me) but you've more details if it happens again, an dagain (ie. is hardware related warning signs)...

Comment: I know this thing that in my system some hardware problem. I don't want to restart it but since it suddenly happened and nothing is working so I restart it. Indeed now I am able to create a new directory.